# Why doesn't this magnet drive produce infinite energy?

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics

[image]

The three large outer magnets are fixed, and the three smaller inner magnets are fixed to each other, rotating around a pivot in the center (yellow arrow). The position of their poles are marked, N for north, S for south. The black arrows show the direction of attraction or repulsion.

The magnets are positioned such that there is always at least two magnets producing net force, as only one magnet may ever be in the "locked" position (i.e. it is directly on top of one of the fixed magnets on the outside).

So why doesn't this produce infinite energy?

Comment: The way that magnets work is that they produce more force when they are closer to the object they are interacting with. The magnet in the "locked" position that you have shown is going to produce a lot more resisting force than the other magnets can produce to push this assembly around. This assembly that you have shown here will just want to stop in the position that have you have shown each time.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: because perpetum mobiles do not work

Longer answer:
Because there is a "point of least energy" frem where rotating the inner ring will need energy. The system will set iteslf into this position automatically and stay there.

IF you don't believe me, it's easy enough to get some magnets and build your system yto test it. It might be easier to understand than.

Comment: A problem that too may people do when coming up with these machines is only look at two positions as if the machine doesn't have a continuum of positions in between. It's like looking at a see saw just at the points when one side is highest and the other side is lowest and concluding it must see-saw forever.

Comment: @DKNguyen I have considered the positions in between. If I didn't, I would not need to include any other magnets other than the three at the very bottom. However, I do realize this is not an appropriate place to ask questions with regard to personal theories.

Comment: @DaPlaneNerd You've just obfuscated the balance point because you've added more things to keep track of but that doesn't mean it's not there. Also remember that it's not just a matter of attraction or repulsion but the magnitudes of each. It's simple enough to build yourself so you can just build it and see what the balance point is.